# Will an IF statement stop evaluating if it fails the first condition?

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

If I have an `If` statement with 2 conditions - and the first fails, will the 2nd condition even be considered or will it go straight to the `else`? So, in the following example, if `myList.Count == 0`, will `myString` be compared against "value" or will it just straight to `else`?

```
if(myList.Count > 0 && myString.Equals("value"))
{
//Do something
}
else
{
//Do something else
}
```

Comment: The *boolean logic operators* in C# are "short circuiting". There, plenty of keywords.

Comment: Note that it's not the `if` statement that is doing this, it's a property of the AND and OR boolan operators.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

It will stop evaluating because you're using the double ampersand && operator. This is called [short-circuiting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator).

If you changed it to a single ampersand:

```
if(myList.Count > 0 & myString.Equals("value"))
```

it would evaluate both.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, +1. When would you actually want to use the & operator then (i.e. when would you even want to look at the 2nd if the 1st condition was false)?

Comment: In this situation you certainly wouldn't. You might use it if your second condition was a function call that performed some updates that you wanted to happen regardless (but I don't know why you'd do that).

Comment: @DeeMac Consider the code: `public bool DoAllWork() { return DoWork() & DoExtraWork(); }` Because we use a single `&` the extra work will be done even if the first method call (`DoWork()`) returns `false`. Had we used `&&` instead, the extra work would only be done if the first call returned `true`. But most programmers never use the `&` operator with booleans, I guess. With integer types (that hold more information than 1 bit), it's another story.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - I suppose it's a concise way of calling two methods and THEN evaluating them in the same 'breath' without having to assign the returns to bool's and then coding a new IF statement. Thanks for your input mate.

Comment: Extremely useful on not null checking, so prioritizing the IsNullOrEmpty will ensure that won't throw an exception if the second condition may do so.

Answer (score 24):

No, it will not be considered. (This is known as [short circuiting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).)

The compiler is clever enough (and required by language specification) to know that if the first condition is `false`, there is no way to expression will evaluate to `true`.

And as Jacob pointed for `||`, when the first condition is `true`, the second condition will not be evaluated.

Comment: And vice-versa with || - the second option will not be evaluated if the first one is `true`.

Answer (score 7):

If the logical operator is AND (&&) then IF statement would evaluate first expression - if the first one is false, it would not evaluate second one. This is useful to check if variable is null before calling method on the reference - to avoid null pointer exception

If the logical operator is OR (||) then IF statement would evaluate first expression - if the first one is true, it would not evaluate second one.

Compilers and runtimes are optimized for this behavior

Answer (score 4):

No, second condition will be skipped if you use `&&`,

If you use `&` it will be considered

Comment: Ah right, didn't realise that was even an operator to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the folowing:

```
static int? x;
static int? y;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    x = 5;
    if (testx() & testy())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    }
}

static Boolean testx()
{
    return x == 3;
}

static Boolean testy()
{
    return y == 10;
}
```

If you trace through both the testx and testy functions are evaulated even though testx was false.

If you change the test to && only the first was checked.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the second statement will only be evaluated if the first fails. The logical AND `&&` will only return `true` when both operands are true, aka *short circuit evaluation*.

Answer (score 1):

.NET supports `short circuiting` so when first condition goes fail, it will not check the second condtion....In C# || and && are the short-circuited versions of the logical operators | and & respectively....It  is often faster too...

Answer (score 0):

The expression will be evaluated from left to right because it is a logical AND operation. If false, it will stop evaluation. It also has the greatest precedence of the operations in your expression.

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary. [Conditional And Operator (&&) <sup>MSDN</sup>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator)

Here is a set of [sections listing the C# operators starting with the highest precedence to the lowest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/).