# Does the order of appearance matter in a single IF statement with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance

I've got a Collection with *up to* 19,000 entries in it that I'm iterating over in a foreach statement. At the beginning of the foreach, I check if a string contains 1 of 2 words and a boolean value, then I either continue or perform some more operations.

```
        foreach (SvnStatusEventArgs e in results) //results being my Collection
        {
            if ((e.Path.Contains("bin") || 
                e.Path.Contains("obj")) && !includeBinObjFolders)
                continue;

            //Do a bunch of things
        }
```

I wasn't sure if the computer would check the string for either "bin" or "obj", and then check the boolean and maybe it'd realize it didn't matter that the strings contained one of those two 'key words'.

Basically I guess what I'm saying is would the following take a different amount of time to run?

```
        foreach (SvnStatusEventArgs e in results) //results being my Collection
        {
            if (!includeBinObjFolders && 
                    (e.Path.Contains("bin") || 
                     e.Path.Contains("obj")
                     )
                )
                continue;

            //Do a bunch of things
        }
```

For some reason, I hear a voice in the back of my head telling me that it evaluates the right-most expression first, and works its way left. If so, the first should be more efficient right? I don't have an easy way of testing a collection larger than ~200 files so simply using a timer yields results that are so close I can't confirm if one way is better.

Frankly I think it's highly unlikely end users will encounter more than 500 pieces of data in this collection at most, but theoretically it could happen due to user error.

**Edit** thanks everyone. I tried searching around before posting here but I forgot the term "short circuiting" in regards to logic so I was having a tough time finding an answer relevant to my wordy title here.

**Edit 2** Actually I just went and created a small console application that had a 2 for loops iterating 20,000 times each. One tested the Contains first, the other tested the Bool first. Repeating these two loops 10 times over, it looks like the boolean first takes on average half of a millisecond per 20K iterations. The Contains being evaluated first takes roughly 3 milliseconds per 20K iterations. A small difference indeed!

Comment: I think you want to read about "short-circuit evaluation". Such as here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358576/will-an-if-statement-stop-evaluating-if-it-fails-the-first-condition) should answer yours.  In your second example, if `!includeBinObjFolders = false` it stops

Comment: In using `&&` your are short circuiting your evaluation.  And in using `||` you are saying that if condition 1 evaluates `true` don't evaluate condition 2.

Comment: In addition to other answers, I just want to tell you that you should use `string.IndexOf` - it is faster than `Contains`. And then, this is your application, you know which condition occurs most. And your code should be cut for that condition, so it is exits quickly most of time.

Comment: @T.S. Made a second Edit testing the various conditions and making note of the results. I also tried comparing IndexOf versus Contains and Contains seems to be at best 2 milliseconds faster and at worst the same amount of time

Comment: value.IndexOf ("s", 0, StringComparison.Ordinal) - should be faster. I think, I've tested it before. But definitely, always pick first condition, the one which should occur more often. Than you bypass evaluation of the following conditions as many times as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given boolean expressions will be evaluated from left to right, not right to left.  The order is indeed defined; it is not arbitrary, nor can it be optimized.  It will always be left to right.

This was specifically called out in the specs so that the side effects of each expression are always executed in a defined order.

You can, if you want, move the boolean variable to the front as an optimization.  It may not be a huge optimization, so don't fret too much over it, but it is an optimization. (Unless of course you know that it will always, or almost always, resolve to `true` while another expression would resolve to false.)

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm not sure how or why I had it backwards.

Unfortunately I'm not really sure if the boolean is more likely to be true or not when this gets used.

Comment: I'd go with the bool check first @sab669, as that is a much cheaper operation than a string compare first

Answer (score 2):

The last expression would probably save you a little more on the runtime as you are only computing a boolean value first. If that's false, the rightmost expression won't even get evaluated, since false AND anything will be false.

Answer (score 2):

Logical operators are processed left to right and `&&` and `||` are shortcircuit operators; meaning

```
x || y // will evaluate x and if it's false, then it will evaluate y
x && y // will evaluate x and if it's true, then it will evaluate y
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691310(v=vs.71).aspx

your second approach would be faster

Comment: Not just the logical operators actually, *all* binary operators are evaluated from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you are [short-circuiting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) your evaluation using `&&`:

```
foreach (SvnStatusEventArgs e in results) //results being my Collection
{
   if (!includeBinObjFolders && 
      (e.Path.Contains("bin") || 
       e.Path.Contains("obj")))
       continue;

   //Do a bunch of things
}
```

So basically, if `!includeBinObjFolders` = `true` stop evaluating.

And in this example, you are using `||`  to evaluate the first two conditions; and if *one* of them is `true` you will stop evaluation.

```
foreach (SvnStatusEventArgs e in results) //results being my Collection
{
   if ((e.Path.Contains("bin") || 
      e.Path.Contains("obj")) && !includeBinObjFolders)
      continue;

      //Do a bunch of things
}
```

I honestly don't think either would be *noticably* faster than the other.  Oh, and as an aside, evaluation is left-to-right, and never right-to-left.

Comment: The main point here is that if your boolean expressions themselves are time consuming to perform (i.e. searching a string could take a while if the string is large, or you could do something like a DB query to get the boolean) then it'll matter.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't care about performance to such an extent, but I figured if I could avoid forty *thousand* String.Contains calls, that should be a lot faster?